# error when validating user input

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a menu-driven program that will generate 5 random integers between 0 and 9, and store them in a List. I want it to then allow the user to enter an integer and then search the List, reporting on the location of the integer in the List (if found) or -1 if not. Then display the result of the search to the screen and re-display the menu.

```
def main():
    choice = displayMenu()
    while choice != '4':
        if choice == '1':
            createList()
        elif choice == '2':
            print(createList)
        elif choice == '3':
            searchList()
        choice = displayMenu()

    print("Thanks for playing!")

def displayMenu():
    myChoice = '0'
    while myChoice != '1' and myChoice != '2' \
                  and myChoice != '3' and myChoice != '4':
         print ("""Please choose
                        1. Create a new list of 5 integers
                        2. Display the list
                        3. Search the list
                        4. Quit
                        """)
         myChoice = input("Enter option-->")

         if myChoice != '1' and myChoice != '2' and \
            myChoice != '3' and myChoice != '4':
             print("Invalid option. Please select again.")

    return myChoice


import random

def linearSearch(myList):
    target = int(input("--->"))
    for i in range(len(myList)):
        if myList[i] == target:
            return i
        return -1


#This will generate the five random numbers from 0 to 9
def createList():
    newList = []
    while True:
        try:
            num = input("Give me five numbers: ")
            num = [int(num) for num in input().split(' ')]
            print(num)
            if any([num < 0 for num in a]):
                Exception

            print("Thank you")
            break
        except:
            print("Invalid. Try again...")

    for i in range(5):
        newList.append(random.randint(0,9))
    return newList


#Option two to display the list
def displayList():
    myList = newList
    print("Your list is: ", newList)



#Option 3 to search the list
def searchList():
    target = int(input("--->"))
    result = linearSearch(myList,target)
    if result == -1:
        print("Not found...")
    else:
        print("Found at", result)




main()
```

However when it prompts the user for the five numbers it says invalid no matter what you enter. Could someone please give me an example on how I could fix this?

Comment: Idk if that causes your problem but it might be better to change your if-statemten `if myChoice != '1' and myChoice != '2' and \
            myChoice != '3' and myChoice != '4':` to `if myChoice not in [1,2,3,4]:`

Comment: As an aside, you might be able to clean up those long if blocks using something like if myChoice not in ['1', '2', '3', '4']:. ... Heh, someone beat me to that advice; +1 @patrick  Taking a closer look at that though, it looks like you are comparing 'strings' and casting to ints. Not sure if that is your problem, but it seems a bit messy to convert back and forth like that.

Comment: Thank you both for that advice to clean up my code! However, it sadly isn't what is causing my problem.

Comment: It does fix the invalid option issue for me edit: actually changing the numbers to ints did; good call @klutt didnt even see that

Comment: When I change it to that as soon as I select number 1 on the menu 'Create a new list of 5 integers' it tells me "Invalid option. Please select again."

Comment: The problem when you use `try...except` without specifying a type of exception, is that you can't then tell what is causing the error. Try removing the `try...except` handling so you can see what error is thrown.

Comment: Please post an mcve when you ask for help: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve For this problem, it would have been enough with just the displayMenu()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK - I found logical and syntax errors at multiple places. I will try to list them as possible.

- Commented out redundent block of choices in `displayMenu()` function.
- fixed main() function. You were not catching values/list returned by
  functions
- Defined `myList` as global list that needed to be passed
- `linearSearch(myList,target)` had extra user input and tweaked logic
  to work. It was only working for finding number at first index.Ideally you can use `list.index(value)` method to get index #
- Commented out extra loop in `createList()` function
- Tweaked functions to receive global list to work properly.

I've tweaked your code as little as possible. Commented out lines not required.
I believe it works as intended.

**Working Code:**

```
def main():
    myList = []
    choice = displayMenu()
    while choice != '4':
        if choice == '1':
            myList =createList()
        elif choice == '2':
            #print(myList)
            displayList(myList)
        elif choice == '3':
            searchList(myList)
        choice = displayMenu()

    print("Thanks for playing!")

def displayMenu():
    myChoice = '0'
    if myChoice != '1' and myChoice != '2' and \
            myChoice != '3' and myChoice != '4':
         print ("""Please choose
                        1. Create a new list of 5 integers
                        2. Display the list
                        3. Search the list
                        4. Quit
                        """)
         myChoice = str(input("Enter option-->"))
         """

         if myChoice != 1 and myChoice != 2 and \
            myChoice != 3 and myChoice != 4:
             print("Invalid option. Please select again.")
            """

    return myChoice


import random

def linearSearch(myList,target):
    #target = int(input("--->"))
    found = False
    for i in range(len(myList)):
        if myList[i] == target:
            found = True
            return i

    if found == False:
        return -1


#This will generate the five random numbers from 0 to 9
def createList():
    print "Creating list..............."
    newList = []
    """
    while True:
        try:
            num = input("Give me five numbers: ")
            num = [int(num) for num in input().split(' ')]
            print(num)

            if any([num < 0 for num in a]):
                Exception

            print("Thank you")
            break

        except:
            print("Invalid. Try again...")

    """
    for i in range(5):        
        newList.append(random.randint(0,9))
        #print newList
    return newList


#Option two to display the list
def displayList(myList):
    #myList = newList
    print("Your list is: ", myList)



#Option 3 to search the list
def searchList(myList):
    target = int(input("--->"))
    #print("Searching for" , target)
    result = linearSearch(myList,target)
    if result == -1:
        print("Not found...")
    else:
        print("Found at", result)

main()
```

**Output**

```
>>> 
Please choose
                        1. Create a new list of 5 integers
                        2. Display the list
                        3. Search the list
                        4. Quit

Enter option-->1
Creating list...............
Please choose
                        1. Create a new list of 5 integers
                        2. Display the list
                        3. Search the list
                        4. Quit

Enter option-->2
('Your list is: ', [1, 4, 6, 9, 3])
Please choose
                        1. Create a new list of 5 integers
                        2. Display the list
                        3. Search the list
                        4. Quit

Enter option-->3
--->4
('Found at', 1)
Please choose
                        1. Create a new list of 5 integers
                        2. Display the list
                        3. Search the list
                        4. Quit

Enter option-->9
Please choose
                        1. Create a new list of 5 integers
                        2. Display the list
                        3. Search the list
                        4. Quit

Enter option-->10
Please choose
                        1. Create a new list of 5 integers
                        2. Display the list
                        3. Search the list
                        4. Quit

Enter option-->3
--->10
Not found...
Please choose
                        1. Create a new list of 5 integers
                        2. Display the list
                        3. Search the list
                        4. Quit

Enter option-->4
Thanks for playing!
>>>
```

Final notes,
You may want to start with something simple such create a menu that  prints different sentences for different choices to see if it works and then go as complex as you wish.

Answer (score 1):

Careful with your input parsing. Either leave input as a string and deal with strings, or initially cast it to an int and continue dealing with ints.

```
myChoice = str(input())
# input 1
if myChoice in ['1', '2', '3', '4']:
  print(myChoice)
```

or

```
myChoice = int(input())
# input 1
if myChoice in [1, 2, 3, 4]:
  print(myChoice)
```

Comment: `str(input())` is not a good idea in either Py2 or Py3: In Py3 it doesn't do anything. in Py2, it is equivalent to `str(eval(raw_input()))`, which will lead to unexpected behavior. `raw_input()` is the better choice in Py2.

Answer (score 1):

In `createList`, you are taking the `input` twice then referring to an undefined variable `a`

```
num = input("Give me five numbers: ")
num = [int(num) for num in input().split(' ')]
...
if any([num < 0 for num in a]):
     Exception
```

should be something like

```
text_input = input("Give me five numbers: ")
numbers = [int(num) for num in text_input.split(' ')]
if any([num < 0 for num in numbers]):
    raise ValueError
```

Your programme has a number of other oddities, but perhaps you're still working on these:

1. You don't do anything with the numbers you have input in `createList` but instead return a list of random numbers. Your description also suggests you want a list of random numbers, so why are you inputting the numbers in the first place?
2. You make variables `myList` and `newList` but your functions won't be able to access these unless you declare them as `global` or explicitly pass them as parameters
3. `linearSearch` can be written more simply using `list.index`:

.

```
def linearSearch(myList, target):
    if target in myList:
        return myList.index(target)
    else:
        return -1
```

Answer (score -1):

Change

```
myChoice = input("Enter option-->")
```

to

```
myChoice = str(input("Enter option-->"))
```

Function **input** returns an integer, and comparison with str will allways return False.

Comment: This is not true. ` a = input(); type(a)`  with an input of 1  returns type str.

Comment: It depends on python version. In python 3.x input function returns str. In python 2.x the input function is equivalent to eval(raw_input(prompt)), therefore you get int if you enter only digits [link](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#input).

Comment: Ah, you're right. I thought it was strange that type(a) returned a string for me, because I did remember what you said to be true. I didn't realize they made that change from python 2.x to 3.x.

Comment: OP is clearly using Py3, otherwise no part of the programme would work. If using Py2, then it's better to use `raw_input` than `str(input())`, because you don't want to evaluate the input.